# How can I convert a base62 (**NOT BASE64**) string into a hexadecimal (base16) string that is around 25 characters long? [Web Development JS]

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to find something to do this for a while, and people have given me really good answers and they do work it's just that Web Development JS doesn't support the amount of characters that I need (~25).

The original script that I was given is below

```
function base62ToHex(base62) {
  base62Charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  const valueOfBase62Char = new Map([...base62Charset].map((char, i) => [char, i]))

  let decimal = 0;
  for (const [i, char] of [...base62].reverse().entries()) {
    decimal += 62**i * valueOfBase62Char.get(char)
  }

  return decimal.toString(16);
};
console.log(base62ToHex("3VOjfwjyAWOKEYNEQOZ8Tsm5RM"))
```

You can see that running this will output

```
>> 6578616d706c68000000000000000000000000
```

Which is where the problem is. Obviously the zeros shouldn't be there and it should be regular hex, but I'm guessing I gave it too much input. Is there a way that I could fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s for arbitrary precision integers:

```js
const base62Charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const valueOfBase62Char = new Map([...base62Charset].map((char, i) => [char, BigInt(i)]));

function base62ToHex(base62) {
  let value = 0n;
  for (const [i, char] of [...base62].reverse().entries()) {
    value += 62n**BigInt(i) * valueOfBase62Char.get(char);
  }

  return value.toString(16);
}

console.log(base62ToHex("3VOjfwjyAWOKEYNEQOZ8Tsm5RM"));
```